# Symmetric set difference in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL supports set operations `UNION`, `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT` to combine the results of the two queries in a certain way:

```
query1 UNION [ALL] query2
query1 INTERSECT [ALL] query2
query1 EXCEPT [ALL] query2
```

The last one is also known as set difference.

---

Is there a reasonable way to make PostgreSQL compute a *symmetric difference*, or "XOR" of the two queries (other than spelling it out)?

```
(query1 EXCEPT query2) UNION (query2 EXCEPT query1)
```

Comment: Are you even sure that's exactly what you want? With null values and duplicates involved, there are *many* nuances. For starters, no keyword `ALL` in your query? By choice?

Comment: First things first. Do you want **Set** Symmetric Difference (no ALL keyword) or **Multiset** Symmetric Difference (with the ALL keyword)?

Answer (score 1):

Examples with data

```
create table a (id int);
insert into a values (1),(2),(3),(4);
create table b (id int);
insert into b values (3),(4),(5),(6);
```

UNION ALL : id(1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6)

```
select * from a
union all
select * from b
order by id
```

UNION: id( 1,2,3,4,5,6)

```
select * from a
union 
select * from b
order by id
```

INTERSECT: id (3,4)

```
select * from a
intersect
select * from b
order by id
```

a EXCEPT b:id(1,2)

```
select * from a
except
select * from b
order by id
```

b EXCEPT a:id(5,6)

```
select * from b
except
select * from a
order by id
```

Your `symmetric difference`, or "XOR"
id(1,2,5,6)

```
(select * from a EXCEPT select * from b) UNION  (select * from b EXCEPT select * from a)
order by id
```

same thing

```
(select * from a union all select * from b) EXCEPT  (select * from b INTERSECT select * from a)
order by id
```

some

```
select id
from(select * from a union all select * from b) x
group by id
having count(*)=1
order by id
```

Classic method

```
select coalesce(a.id,b.id) id 
from a
full OUTER join  b on a.id=b.id
where ( a.id is null or b.id is null)
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/z_dVkXmL)

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN every time

Comment: The full outer join works properly for a single column. For tables with multiple columns the long form is much easier to write.